# A Tribonacci numbers identity for Pythagorean quadruples $a^2+b^2+c^2 =d^2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

We have the known Fibonacci identity for *Pythagorean triples*,

$$(F_n F_{n+3})^2+(2F_{n+1}F_{n+2})^2 = (F_{2n+3})^2$$

and for Lucas numbers,

$$(L_n L_{n+3})^2+(2L_{n+1}L_{n+2})^2 = (L_{2n+2}+L_{2n+4})^2 = (5F_{2n+3})^2$$

But given the [*tribonacci numbers*](http://oeis.org/A000073),

$$T_n = 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 24, 44, 81, 149, 274, 504, 927, 1705, 3136,\dots$$

where we set $T_0 = 0,\; T_1 = 1$, etc, it seems they obey the analogous *Pythagorean quadruples*,

$$(-T_{n+3}^2+T_{2n+3}+T_{2n+4})^2+(2\,T_n\,T_{n+1})^2+(2\,T_n\,T_{n+2})^2 = (T_{n-1}^2+\,T_{2n+1}+T_{2n+2})^2$$

Some questions:

1. This relation was discovered empirically and holds true for $n$ up to the hundreds, but it would be good to know a proof that it is true for all $n$.
2. Any tribonacci analogue for higher powers, like ([eq.30](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FibonacciNumber.html)) $F_{n+1}^3+F_n^3-F_{n-1}^3 = F_{3n}$?

Comment: Expand the $T_n$s maybe?

Comment: The LHS and RHS won't cancel out easily. (I'm also trying to find the _tetranacci_ analogue, but it's proving a tad more difficult.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An "arithmetic" subsequence of a linear recurrent sequence is again a linear recurrent sequence, of the same order.

A product of linear recurrent sequences (of order $a$ and $b$) is again a linear recurrent sequence, of order at most $ab$.

A sum of linear recurrent sequences (of order $a$ and $b$) is again a linear recurrent sequence, of order at most $a+b$.

Hence, the difference $(-T_{n+3}^2+T_{2n+3}+T_{2n+4})^2+(2\,T_n\,T_{n+1})^2+(2\,T_n\,T_{n+2})^2 - (T_{n-1}^2+\,T_{2n+1}+T_{2n+2})^2$ is a linear recurrent sequence, of order at most $702$. So in order to prove that it is the zero sequence, you can just compute the first $702$ values.

You can cut down on the order (because $T_{1400}$ is not really a small number, right ?) by keeping track at each step of the roots of the characteristic polynomial of the recurrence.

Comment: My apologies, it took me ten years to notice I didn't click on the button! (I should review all my questions.)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding *Question 2*, after a session with *Mathematica*, it turns out that the Fibonacci identity,

$$-F_{n-1}^3+\color{brown}{F_n^3}+F_{n+1}^3 = F_{3n}$$

has a Tribonacci analogue for third (and higher) powers though they are more complicated. The Fibonacci uses only *three* addends, while the Tribonacci has ***twelve*** addends,

$$\sum_{m=-7}^4 c_m\, T_{n+m}^3= T_{3n}$$

and the $c_m$ are constants. Explicitly,

$$a + 30\, \color{brown}{T_n^3} + b  = 412\, T_{3n}$$

where,

$$\begin{aligned}
a &= 6\,T_{n-7}^3+11\,T_{n-6}^3+18\,T_{n-5}^3-48\,T_{n-4}^3-24\,T_{n-3}^3-16\,T_{n-2}^3+24\,T_{n-1}^3\\[2.5mm]
b &=-10\, T_{n+1}^3+5\, T_{n+2}^3+2\, T_{n+3}^3+2\,T_{n+4}^3
\end{aligned}$$

For example, let $n=8$ and $T_8 = 44$, then,

$$6(1^3)+11(1^3)+ 18(2^3) -48(4^3) -24(7^3) -16(13^3)+ 24(24^3)+ 30(44^3) -10(81^3) +5(149^3)+ 2(274^3)+ 2(504^3) = 412\,T_{24} = 412(755476)$$

though it holds true for all integer $n\geq 7$.